# How to add a given line after a specific one in a file with sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

I am writing a bash file that edit another file with sed. I am looking to add a new line after the line that reads:

```
echo "rpcallowip=127.0.0.1\n";
```

the added line will read

```
echo "rpcallowip=$webip\n";
```

The new output of `example.conf` will then read

```
echo "rpcallowip=127.0.0.1\n";
echo "rpcallowip=10.0.0.1\n";
```

It is important the line keeps the " " as shown.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. For example, do you mean that you are writing a bash script, or that you are using sed to edit a file, or both? If all you want is to have sed replace `127.0.0.1` with `$webip`, then  try `sed 's/127.0.0.1/$webip/'. However, I suspect you are trying to say you want to do more.

Comment: sorry edit to make the question more clear.

Comment: The expected output does not seem to contain the line that you said you wanted to add... It would additionally be useful to know if it is in the middle or very end of the file that you would like to add the new line (it's trivial to add a line to the end of a file).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I have the file `file` with content

```
text
text text
echo "rpcallowip=127.0.0.1\n";
text
text text
```

To append a line after the line with `echo` using `sed`:

```
sed '/^echo "rpcallowip=127.0.0.1\\n";$/a\
echo "rpcallowip=$webip\\n";
' file
```

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed '/^echo "rpcallowip=127.0.0.1\\n";$/a echo "rpcallowip=$webip\\n";' file
```

In both examples, we are first matching the literal line that we'd like to add the text after, from start to finish, and then we append the wanted text using the `sed` command `a` ("append"). The `\` in `\n` needs to be escaped an extra time in both the pattern and in the text being inserted (and to be extra pedantic, each dot in the IP address in the pattern should be `\.`).

The result of above operation is the output

```
text
text text
echo "rpcallowip=127.0.0.1\n";
echo "rpcallowip=$webip\n";
text
text text
```

Answer (score 0):

The brute force simple way to use `sed` to add a line `echo "rpcallowip=$webip\n";` after an existing line `echo "rpcallowip=127.0.0.1\n";` in some file named `example.conf` is:

```
sed 's/echo "rpcallowip=127.0.0.1\\n";/echo "rpcallowip=127.0.0.1\\n";\necho "rpcallowip=$webip\\n";/' example.conf
```

Note that three of the four new-line characters `\n` needed to be escaped with a leading back-slash `\` in order not to actually treated as new-lines.

Is that what you are trying to accomplish?

The more idiomatic solution is to use `sed` *grouping*:

```
sed 's/\(echo "rpcallowip=127.0.0.1\\n";\)/\1\necho "rpcallowip=$webip\\n";/' example.conf
```

In this second `sed` example, `\(` and `\)` demarcate a `sed` *group*, and `\1` refers to the first group previously demarcated (in this case the only group).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sed too

```
webip='10.0.0.1'
sed -E '
h
s/(echo "rpcallowip=)([0-9.]*)(.*)/\1'"$webip"'\3/
tA
b
:A
x
p
x
' infile
```